# How to specify minimal and maximal version of dependency in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Assume that package `localization@2.0.0` requires peer dependency of package `library` of minimal version `1.1.0` and maximal version`1.5.4`. With JavaScript, the logical expression will be:

```js
libraryVersion >= 1.1.0 && libraryVersion <= 1.5.4
```

But how to express same condition in `peerDependencies` (and other types of dependencies) filed of package.json? I did not find the logic operator `and` in [semver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) documentation.

```json
{
  "peerDependencies": {
     "library": ">=1.2.7 "
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. You can do something like `"library": "1.x"` but that's it.